# Access JavaScript object variable from function

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following code below, but one problem.
I want to access a variable from inside the function clslevel() named the_id, from the calling anonymous function. I tried this.the_id but it returns undefined.

```js
function clslevel(id){ 
  var the_id = id;
  this.methodOne=function(param){
    param();
    return this;
  };
  this.methodTwo=function(param){
    param();
    return this;
  };
  
}


function level(id){
  return new clslevel(id);
}



level("myButton")
  .methodOne(
    function(){
      console.log("methodOne called.");
      // how can I access the variable 'the_id' in clslevel() from here?
    }  
  )
  .methodTwo(
    function(){
      console.log("methodTwo called");
    }  
  )
```

thank you in advance!

Comment: You can't. Absolutely. That's how scope works. What problem are you actually trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a reference of your object so you can use the parent functions inside the other scope

```js
function clslevel(id){ 
  this.the_id = id;
  this.methodOne=function(param){
    param(this);
    return this;
  };
  this.methodTwo=function(param){
    param(this);
    return this;
  };
  
}


function level(id){
  return new clslevel(id);
}



level("myButton")
  .methodOne(
    function(parent){
      console.log("methodOne called.");
      console.log('the_id = ' + parent.the_id)
      // how can I access the variable 'the_id' in clslevel() from here?
    }  
  )
  .methodTwo(
    function(){
      console.log("methodTwo called");
    }  
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

Pass it as a parameter to the function, like this:

```js
function clslevel(id){ 
  var the_id = id;
  this.methodOne=function(param){
    param(the_id);
    return this;
  };
  this.methodTwo=function(param){
    param();
    return this;
  };
  
}


function level(id){
  return new clslevel(id);
}



level("myButton")
  .methodOne(
    function(the_id){
      console.log("methodOne called.", the_id);
      // You have the_id here
    }  
  )
  .methodTwo(
    function(){
      console.log("methodTwo called");
    }  
  )
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass this variable into callback:

```
function clslevel(id){ 
  var the_id = id;
  this.methodOne=function(param){
    param(the_id);
    return this;
  };
  this.methodTwo=function(param){
    param();
    return this;
  };

}


function level(id){
  return new clslevel(id);
}



level("myButton")
  .methodOne(
    function(passed_id){
      console.log("methodOne called.");
      console.log(passed_id)
      // how can I access the variable 'the_id' in clslevel() from here?
    }  
  )
  .methodTwo(
    function(){
      console.log("methodTwo called");
    }  
  )
```